# Can I install counter strike on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: games

Can I install counter strike on Ubuntu 22.04 ? I need to install counter strike 1.6 on my laptop

Comment: We don't accept yes/no questions.  Start by looking at the tool you want to play it with: steam? wine? and follow their instructions :)